# Objective-C classes in Swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

I'm currently an A-level student completing a project as part of my project. I am making an iOS app and am new to Xcode. I used the tutorial from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=juMWo5wniKg to use a tick box feature within my application. I followed what the speaker said and ran (command b) the code at point 3:30 in the video. My build failed and the error was as follows:

> <unknown>:0: error: error opening input file '/Users/robert/Documents/A2/Computer science/APP/first App/CheckMarkHeader.h' (No such file or directory)

The header name is called 'CheckMarkHeader.h' and is in Xcode so I don't understand how the file is not available. It all went bit upside down when I copied an pasted

```
#import "BEMCheckBox.h"
```

into the header named 'CheckMarkHeader.h'

Comment: you might have circular imports, A including B which includes C which in turn includes A again.

Comment: I thought that Computer Science is about sorting algorithms, trees and computational complexity...

Comment: @kelin We do more then that haha

Comment: @luk2302 - `#import` automatically handles circular imports, ensuring each file is only imported once.

Answer (score 0):

While adding **Objective-C Bridging Header** in **"Swift Compiler-General"** you should add the project name before **"CheckMarkHeader.h"**. Let's, if your project name is **"CheckMark"** then add **"CheckMark/CheckMarkHeader.h"** as your Objective-C Bridging Header. Hopes it will help you.

Comment: @robert - Have you tried it ? Let us know your feedback.

Comment: Yes, i tried it out but it didn't end up working thank you for your help anyway. Im just looking to create a check/tick box that can be used on a consent form for the user to tick if the they agree to the form, found this toro rial and thought the animation would look good but I can't get it to work

Comment: I have checked with this and it's work for me. What's problem you are facing now ? Share with us.

Comment: Ive actually stopped with that problem since it wasn't working for me and I couldn't solve the problem. I'm using a different method now but I'm getting the syntax error ' Thread 1: signal SIGABRT'. What does this mean?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a problem as you must have Not Mentioned your Bridging-Header Path

Go to **Build-Settings** search for keyword **bridging Header** you will get the option Objective-c Bridging Header there mention path of your Header file

For example : ProjectName/NameOfBridgingHeader.h

Answer (score -1):

Circular imports seems to be the correct answer. For ObjC, try to import all the classes in the .m file and use @class if necessary in the header to silence the compiler error.

Comment: thanks! Ill research on that more, however what do you mean by @class ?

Comment: `#import` automatically handles circular *imports*, ensuring each file is only imported once. Circular *dependencies* between types is a different matter, and that is where`@class` is used.

Comment: So let's say you want to use class B in class A as a property in the header and there is a circular reference so you have to move the #import to the .m file, in order to silence the compiler warns you the class B is not existing in the header of class A you need to do @class ClassB at the top, indicates "Hey compiler, I know this class exists and I'll provide details in the .m file so stop warning me"